# Absolute positioned image displays when parent is flipped

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've come across a weird bug in Chrome (works fine in Firefox), not sure how to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GkXA7/1/ When hovering over the card the image show's up flipped on the backside of the card. However if I position the image from the right it doesn't happen!? http://jsfiddle.net/GkXA7/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front card">
            <img width="40" height="40" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg">
            <h3>Front</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="back card">
            <h3>Back</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Flip Effect */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.flipper .card {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
.flipper .front{
    background-color:green;
}
.flipper .back{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background-color:red;
}
.front img{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the image from appearing on the flip side while still being able to position it absolutely?

Comment: Oh goodie, yet another backface-visibility bug. Have you filed a bug on Blink yet? Probably WebKit too, but don't have Safari available right now. I bet there's some sort of trickery to work around this, but I need to test a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is almost on the same z position that the backface, so it sometimes show and sometimes don't.

See the [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkXA7/3/)

I just changed that:

```
.flipper .back{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg)  translateZ(-1px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(-1px);
    background-color:red;
}
```

1 pixel makes a difference !

Seems that misread your requirement, and that what you want is exactly the opposite.

[first fiddle corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/GkXA7/4/)

Of course now I translating the pixel in positive !

The final reason that on one side shows and on the other not is that the 180 deg rotation is really a little bit less, say 179.99 deg. So the right side is a little bit "down" and the left side a little bit "up"